# Join where date is not in any row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table in Sql-server

[image]

What I want to do is return all Breaks that has no row in DeletedBreaks with corresponding BreakId and Date that comes as input from the application.
I tried following and it returns all rows that has not input date. These dates should not be picked out.

```
Select B.* From Breaks B JOIN TimeIntervals T ON B.TimeIntervalId=T.Id 
JOIN DeletedBreaks DB ON DB.BreakId=B.Id 
Where DB.BreakId IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS  
(Select DeletedDate From DeletedBreaks Where BreakId=B.Id AND DeletedDate = '2014-11-14') AND (T.Id = 1 )
```

So in the example tables above it should not return a row because there is a row in the DeletedBreaks table with the input date.

The Date field is supposed to indicate that no rows should be returned for this or any other date that has a value in this field.

Help will be greatly appreciated

**Update**

I have also tried following approach witch can help distinguish what I dont want.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Breaks b
LEFT JOIN DeletedBreaks db ON db.BreakId = b.Id
WHERE db.Date <> @DeletedDate
OR    db.BreakId IS NULL
```

The problem with this is that it returns all rows that has a date in DeletedBreaks.DeletedDate that does not match input date witch is not what I want, I the only thing that is supposed to generate result is if there is no DeletedBreaks.DeletedDate that is the same as input date

**Update 2**

```
SELECT b.*
FROM Breaks b
LEFT JOIN DeletedBreaks db ON db.BreakId = b.Id
WHERE db.DeletedDate = @DeletedDate
OR db.BreakId IS NULL
```

Above is the opposite to what i want I want all to return result when the date is not in the field DeletedDate, bud <> don't solve the problem because then every other date for that breakId will be returned, and it should only be result returned if the input date is in DeletedDate, every other date should be ignored.

**UPDATE 3**

I'll try to be more clear and give one more example:

[image]

```
Select B.* From Breaks B JOIN TimeIntervals T ON B.TimeIntervalId=T.Id 
JOIN DeletedBreaks DB ON DB.BreakId=B.Id 
Where DB.BreakId IS NULL OR NOT EXISTS  
(Select DeletedDate From DeletedBreaks Where BreakId=B.Id AND DeletedDate = '2014-11-14') AND (T.Id = 1 )
```

If input date is 2014-11-14 and input for TimeInterval.Id = 1, then there should be no result (because the break with Id = 1 has been deleted that day.)

If input date is 2014-11-15 and input for TimeInterval.Id = 1, then all Breaks with TimeIntervalID = 1 should be returned. (Break with Id 1 is returned)

The DeletedDate field in DeletedBreaks table indicates that a break is deleted for that particular date and TimeintervalId, 
therefore it should not return breaks when that date is selected for input.

A break with for example id 1 should be returned if there is no row in DeletedBreaks with BreakId = 1 and a date that matches the input date witch in the example sql is static but in my app Changes depending on what is being selected in the app.

Comment: Please [edit] the title of your question to describe the problem. As written, it has zero meaning; we can tell it's related to SQL from your tags, and you clearly need help or you wouldn't be posting here. The title should say something about the specific problem, and should be something that will have meaning  when it turns up in a search result by future users of this site when they're looking for a solution for their problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for getting all Breaks.Ids that are not in the DeletedBreaks table:

```
SELECT B.Id, B.TimeIntervalID
FROM Breaks B
WHERE B.Id NOT IN ( SELECT BreakID from DeletedBreaks)
```

Comment: Thanks, but is should sometimes return Breaks even though there is a corresponding Id in DeletedBreaks, in fact it should Always do that if input date is not in the field DeletedDate

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did not correctly understand what you need. And I'm still not sure if I do now. Does this query what you need?

```
DECLARE @DeletedDate DATE = '2014-11-14'

SELECT b.*
FROM Breaks b
LEFT JOIN DeletedBreaks db ON db.BreakId = b.Id
WHERE db.Date = @DeletedDate
OR    db.BreakId IS NULL
```

Hope this helps. If not, it might help if you provide an example with more rows and the desired query result.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that approach but the problem is that it returns all rows that has a date in DeletedBreaks.DeletedDate that does not match input date witch is not what I want, I the only thing that is supposed to generate result is if there is no DeletedBreaks.DeletedDate that is the same as input date.

Comment: The update will return result if the date matches input date. I want it to return result if the date is not in the table, and at the samt time not return other rows that do not match the date. The breakes is shared between timeIntervals with intervalId in Breaks table. But on some dates I what to be able to delete a break but that will happen very seldom.

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand what you need. What do you mean by "the date is not in the table" ... you mean anywhere in the table? Can you please provide an example with several rows and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Two of the possible ways to get the desired result:

Use a left join with a condition for d.BreakID=b.ID and DeletedDate=@DeletedDate and exclude those with a DeletedDate

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM Breaks b
JOIN TimeIntervals T ON b.TimeIntervalId=T.Id 
LEFT JOIN DeletetBreaks d ON d.BreakID=b.ID and d.DeletedDate=@DeletedDate
WHERE d.DeletedDate is NULL
```

Or exclude those ID's with matching ID'S from a subquery fitting your conditions

```
SELECT b.* 
FROM @Breaks b
JOIN TimeIntervals T ON b.TimeIntervalId=T.Id 
WHERE b.ID not in (SELECT BreakID FROM @DeletetBreaks where DeletedDate=@DeletedDate )
```